# Azure Information Protection - Error: Policy is Missing

Tags: azure

I have setup Azure Information Protection with the scanner. The scanner is installed on a server, and the server registers in the Azure Information Protection window. I can see it there. It continually displays "Error: Policy is missing". I have a policy configured though and I have labels in Azure Information Protection. What am I missing?

Comment: We have one AIP scanner that works fine, I just set another one up today to help with scan jobs since I added a lot more scan repositories, and I have the same error. Is your scanner version 2.7.99.0? That is the version of the new one I set up. The old one that works is 1.54.33.0

Answer (score 1):

Hey I just ran into this same scenario and for the life of me could not get it to resolve. I had ran into it the other day and was able to run the Start-AIPDiagnostics and it came back with that the token had expired. I renewed the token and it came bakc up and I was able to kick off a test scan, but then today the error came back and the diagnostics said everything was good. The scanner version was 2.7.93.0 and it persisted even after an upgrade to 2.7.99.0.

Right now, it looks to be resolved, but I had to uninstall the AIP Scanner Service and re-install. This does nto require much work and I did it following these steps in admin powershell:

1. Uninstall-AIPScanner
2. Restart the server
3. Install-AIPScanner -SQLServerInstance (your instance location) -Cluster (cluster name in the AIP Scanner portal)
4. Renew the token using the following commands:

$pscreds = Get-Credential "domain\serviceaccount"

Set-AIPAuthentication -AppId "APP_ID" -AppSecret "APP_SECRET" -TenantId "TENANT_ID" -DelegatedUser (service account UPN in Office 365) -OnBehalfOf $pscreds

Everything looks to have come back up fine, and I will be keeping an eye out for it.

EDIT: The error did come back, and I had to engage Microsoft Support to resolve the issue. The final root cause was that the server and the AIP admin center had become out of sync and the engineer advised deleted the MSIP folder and letting it rebuild itself when launching the AIP client again. The MSIP folder can be found at C:\Users\scanneraccount\AppData\Local\Microsoft. It should force the server to get everything again and cause it to re-sync.

During my conversations with the engineer, I also found out that you may encounter this issue if you have multiple scanners using the same service account and one job is set to continuous scanning. If you are using the same service account, it will work fine if both jobs are manual and kicked off at different times.

I of course asked for any documentation on this and they could not provide any.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and it took me a month to figure to out how to fix it. The main issue was that the server on which the scanner was installed could NOT connect to the internet or the security and compliance center. So it could not pull the policy and I had to manually put the policy on the server.

Here's how to fix that:

1. From a computer with internet connectivity that has the unified labeling client installed and signed in with the user account - run the Export-AIPLogs cmdlet, or use the Export Logs option from the client's Help and Feedback dialog box.
2. The log files are exported as a single compressed file.
   Open the compressed file, and from the MSIP folder, copy any files that have a .xml file name extension.
3. Paste these files into the %localappdata%\Microsoft\MSIP folder on the disconnected computer or scanner server (if disconnected)

For more - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/information-protection/rms-client/clientv2-admin-guide-customizations#support-for-disconnected-computers